# How can I stop Nautilus from caching thumbnails?

Tags: cache, thumbnails

In Nautilus, I want to see thumbnails on the fly, but I don't want them to be cached. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you `sudo` into gconf-editor goto `/desktop/gnome/thumbnail_cache` and set the `maximum_age` to `1`. The thumbnails will stay around for 1 day as for permanently disabling caching I am not sure.

Comment: You don't need sudo to open `gconf-editor`.